# How to setup a multi-lingual site on IIS

Tags: localization, windows

I've been trying to setup my site on IIS, which runs fine on Apache, without success.

My setup is this (with rewrites)
/ (loads craft for the admin panel)
/en (loads the english homepage)
/fr (loads the french homepage)

The root works without any issues so the web.config does its job.
The same web.config lives in the fr and en folder, but as soon as I try to get in there, I hit a 500.

If I remove the web.config from those 2 folders, I get the homepage of each language, but nothing for the entries.

Anywone knows how to get it to work ?

I'm also trying to get everything working with a single php file that checks for the lang in the p parameter and sets it, but Craft doesn't receive the good slug, even if I modify the p parameter to remove the language.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it was only because I was missing the clear tag in my rules in the subfolders.  Everything works like a charm now.